# Why do I have to call applyBindings again after changing view model's property?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GhFuS/1/).

I have a view model where part of the data will be available after some user interaction.

Since the `applyBindings` is already called at document ready, why is it necessary to call again during a button click event?

HTML:

```
<p>first name:
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: ray.firstName" />
</p>
<p>last name:
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: ray.lastName" />
</p>
<p>first name:
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: joe.firstName" />
</p>
<p>last name:
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: joe.lastName" />
</p>
```

JS:

```
function person(firstNm, lastNm) {
    this.firstName = firstNm;
    this.lastName = lastNm;
}

function myApp() {
    this.ray = new person();
    this.joe = new person();
}

var app = new myApp();
app.ray = new person('ray', 'cheng');
ko.applyBindings(app);

$('#showName').on('click', function () {
    app.joe = new person('joe', 'public');
    ko.applyBindings(app); // <-- why is this needed since applyBindings already called above.
});
```

Comment: I'd suggest taking some time to go through knockout.js's [tutorials](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/). They're very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `applyBindings` twice because you are not using [observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html). And without the observables Knockout is not able to track that your objects are changed so it cannot change the UI.

So your view model should look like this:

```
function app() {
    this.ray = ko.observable(new person());
    this.joe = ko.observable(new person());
}
```

And because `ko.observable` returns a function you need to set them like this:

```
app.ray(new person('ray', 'cheng'));
app.joe(new person('joe', 'public'));
```

And to get the value in a `data-bind` expression you need to call the `ko.observable` without any argument like `ray().firstName` to get its value:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: ray().firstName" />
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/4wW7s/)